# Versus tag and word-choice tag...redundant?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of this writing, 40 questions are tagged `word-choice` and 35 are tagged `versus`. Almost everything tagged versus could also be tagged `word-choice` (except for a couple which would be `word-order`).  My instinct is to kill the `versus` tag altogether since I don't feel like it adds any value, but I don't want to do that without checking with the community.

Comment: I have prescriptivist leanings -- y'all have no idea how difficult it is for me to start a discussion instead of arbitrarily and capriciously creating a rule and insisting that everyone follow it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that *versus* should be used on questions where users ask about one word / phrase against another one (*"right" versus "correct"*), and *word-choice* when the question asks which word to use without to offer two alternative words / phrases.

The two questions are different. In the first case of questions, users who ask the question only want to know if to use the first word, or the second; in the second case, the user doesn't have a clue of what word (or phrase) should use.

Comment: An interesting point, but then again, whenever I was looking for a word myself, I was rather tempted to tag my question "looking-for-a-word" or some such, but never "word-choice". "Choice" implies that there are several alternatives, that there is, well, a choice. However, when I am looking for a word that means X, I have no idea whether I will be offered *several* words to choose from, or in fact *any at all*.

Comment: Also, I feel like "word-choice" is best applied to single words. When I am looking for a word combination or an entire sentence, "wording" would seem more appropriate.

Comment: I think that _versus_ should be kept if there is a reason to group that set of questions together. This is the main purpose of using tags, IMO. Clearly, a tag is useful if users understand what the purpose of the tag is.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that when I first started contributing, my subjective impression was that the `versus` tag was being used more often than the `word-choice` tag. Shame on me, I didn't bother to actually check the stats, and ended up tagging at least three of my own questions `versus` (and none of them `word-choice`).

In other words, if it weren't for me, the `versus` tag would be even less popular (and the `word-choice` would be used even more).

I also think that while `versus` is shorter, `word-choice` is a bit more self-explanatory, probably even more so to foreign learners.

I will thus start re-tagging my own questions accordingly (though not too hastily, so as not to pollute the front page).

I also suggest that someone with enough rep [adds `versus` as a tag synonym for `word-choice`](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/word-choice/info), so that future questions tagged `versus` are automatically re-tagged behind the scenes.

Oh, and do cast your votes for [all the other tag synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) out there! (If you have more than 1000 rep points, that is.)

Comment: I will submit `versus` as a synonym for `word-choice`.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Unfortunately, only nine other people can vote on it. When the temporary moderators are appointed, they will be able to instantly approve synonyms, so we may have to wait until then.